# OpenLayers plugin QGIS 2.0.1

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, qgis-plugins

I have installed QGIS 2.0.1, great thing, but the OpenLayers plugin doesn't work correctly.  When I try to load two different layers I get the answer "could not draw Google satellite because:..."

Also there are problems with loading one map. The correct display is only possible in the OpenLayers projection EPSG:3852, when I try to change the project projection the display gets wrong. This is depending on the zoom factor of the display. At the same time the OpenLayers collapses.

I set the project properties on "on the fly"...

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your problem. What exactly is your Issue? Are you trying to use the Plugin when your Map is in a Spatial Reference Other than EPSG:3857? the OpenLayers Plugin works only in this projection.

Comment: o.k. this is only one problem, in 1.8 I could change to other projections without problems. But when I start a new project and load e.g google physical all is fine but when I add e.g. gooogle sattelite and want to switch between the layers I got error message " could not draw google.." it was all easy with 1.8 and now all is difficult and I wonder where the problem is